# SQL combine rows based on group by in view

Tags: sql, sql-view

I have a table:

```
c1    c2
----------
A    B
A    C
X    P
X    Q
```

How can i create a view that shows this as

```
c1    c2    c3
---------------
A    B    C
X    P    Q
```

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample table data, and adjust the wanted result accordingly.

Comment: @jarlh i've expanded the example, there will always be two rows like this which I need to combine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self join the table:

```
select
  t1.c1, t1.c2, t2.c2 as c3
from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
on t1.c1 = t2.c1 and t1.c2 < t2.c2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dKkqL7obQLDSh2oWeG5d5z/1).
Results:

```
| c1  | c2  | c3  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A   | B   | C   |
| X   | P   | Q   |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select c1, min(c2) as c2, max(c2) as c3
from t
group by c1;
```

Comment: these are strings, so won't be able to do `min` or `max`, I've expanded the example a bit more for clarity

Comment: @S_S . . . Why not?  `min()` and `max()` work fine on strings.  This is definitely the most reasonable answer to the question.